# Add user custom action in list ribbon using powershell?

Tags: 2010, list, powershell, ribbon, custom-actions

I would like to add multiple User Custom Actions on several sites using PowerShell. The custom actions must be added in the top ribbon that is visible when selecting a list item. Is that even possible? 
When looking at SPList **userCustomActions** property, it is readonly, according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.usercustomactions.aspx) . Am I taking the wrong path? The property is readonly but the custom actions are there, so they must have been added.

So far I've been there.

```
$w = get-spweb $webUrl;
$l = $w.lists[$listTitle];
$userCustomActions = $l.userCustomActions;
```

Of course, custom Actions can be added via JS, C# + feature, SharePoint Designer. But I can't use those methods, So I'm only interested in PowerShell procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `UserCustomActions.Add()` method to add the custom action.

Try and modify the below code:

```
$web = get-spweb $webUrl;
$list = $web.Lists[$listTitle];
$action = $list.UserCustomActions.Add();

$action.Url = "someurlhere";
$action.Location = "Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.Controls._children";
$action.Sequence = 85;
$action.Title = "Test Action";
$action.Description  = "Test Action description";

$action.Update();
```

MSDN - [SPUserCustomActionCollection.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spusercustomactioncollection.add(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Thank you @Gautam. I realize that even if the code is not writing in PowerShell, (ex : C#, JavaScript) the methods exposed by objects, most of the time, have the same signature and can be used the same way.

Comment: Welcome, glad i could help :) , fyi - almost anything that's possible via c# ssom code is doable via powershell, just minor changes in syntax.